# How to subset a matrix retaining colums and rows that sum more than 0?

Tags: r, matrix

I need to subset a matrix retaining only columns that sum more than 0 AND retaining also rows that sum more than 0.

This is my best try but it does not work:

```
clean_data <- data [,colSums(data)!=0] & [rowSums(data)!=0,]

Given this matrix:

0 1 0 2 3;
0 0 0 0 1;
0 0 0 0 0;
1 0 0 2 0;

I need this matrix:

0 1 2 3;
0 0 0 1;
1 0 2 0;
```

In addition, how can now make a squared matrix? Same number of columns and rows, that is, all column names present in the rows and viceversa).

Comment: are all entries non-negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the matrix you 'need', Try this:

```
> dat <- matrix(
   data = c(0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,3,1,0,0),
   nrow = 4,
   ncol = 5
 )

> dat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    0    2    3
[2,]    0    0    0    0    1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    2    0

> dat[rowSums(dat) > 0, colSums(dat) > 0]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    2    3
[2,]    0    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    2    0
```

Comment: I think OP wanted the colSums > 0 and the rowSums > 1

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure which OP actually wanted. So I went ahead and edited my response to show both.

Comment: Sorry, I want rowSums >0 as well, I made an error writing the question.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure I adjusted it appropriately, please accept the answer.

Comment: I see you added that you want a `squared matrix`. I'm not sure what exactly you want. If you just want to square all the values, you can simply `dat^2`.

Comment: I want to have the same colnames and the same rownames, even if they are empty (all 0s). Similarly to an identity matrix.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is `dat0[dat0 > 0] <- 1`, where `dat0 = dat[rowSums(dat) > 0, colSums(dat) > 0]`.